# Hide labels on jfreechart/PiePlot3D piechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to get the jfreechart PieChart3D to hide labels. I can't find anything in the documentation.

Anyone know how to do this?

```
<% response.setContentType("image/png"); %><%@page import="org.jfree.data.general.*"%><%@page import="org.jfree.chart.*"%><%@page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.*"%><%@page import="java.awt.Color" %><%

            DefaultPieDataset ds = (DefaultPieDataset)session.getAttribute("usagePieOutputDataset");

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D
            (
                null,   // Title
                ds,     // Dataset
                false,  // Show legend
                false,  // Use tooltips
                false   // Configure chart to generate URLs?
            );

            chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
            chart.setBorderVisible(false);

            PiePlot3D plot = ( PiePlot3D )chart.getPlot();
            plot.setDepthFactor(0.0);
            plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            plot.setLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial",  java.awt.Font.BOLD, 10));


            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart, 150, 144);
    %>
```

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/PiePlot3D.html

Comment: Did you check my answer? No comment on it and also not accepted. Does this not work for you? Or isn't what you want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will hide all labels:

```
plot.setLabelGenerator(null); //null means no labels
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually this seems to be an even easier way and also much shorter.

Just do the label distribution yourself (anonymous implementation) and pretend that there are no labels to display by returning a zero in `getItemCount()`.

```
plot.setLabelDistributor(new AbstractPieLabelDistributor() {
    public int getItemCount() { return 0; }
    public void distributeLabels(double minY,double height) {}
});
```

---

Old solution:

Don't know if there is an easier way but this should work. Should be self-explanatory. Don't show links set some colors transparent and don't generate labels. Else just ask.

```
Color transparent = new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
plot.setLabelLinksVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(transparent);
plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(transparent);
plot.setLabelShadowPaint(transparent);
plot.setLabelGenerator(new PieSectionLabelGenerator(){
    @Override
    public AttributedString generateAttributedSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
        return new AttributedString("");
    }
    @Override
    public String generateSectionLabel(PieDataset dataset, Comparable key) {
        return "";
    }
});
```

Comment: So? Does this do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
```